# How to Concat string to a number in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have Table_A like this below

```
SALDO_AWAL_TAHUN   YTD_AMOUNT_JAN  YTD_AMOUNT_FEB  YTD_AMOUNT_MAR  BRANCH_ID
100                200             300             400             001a
```

YTD_AMOUNT_JAN means amount of January, YTD_AMOUNT_FEB means amount of February, etc What I want is I can make select based on the month.I  make already function to define a month as parameter.

```
FUNCTION GET_MONTH_NAME (P_MONTH INT)
      RETURN VARCHAR
   IS
      V_RESULT   VARCHAR (20);
   BEGIN
      SELECT   CASE
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 1 THEN 'JAN'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 2 THEN 'FEB'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 3 THEN 'MAR'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 4 THEN 'APR'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 5 THEN 'MAY'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 6 THEN 'JUN'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 7 THEN 'JUL'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 8 THEN 'AUG'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 9 THEN 'SEP'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 10 THEN 'OCT'
                  WHEN P_MONTH = 11 THEN 'NOV'
                  ELSE 'DEC'
               END
        INTO   V_RESULT
        FROM   DUAL;


      RETURN V_RESULT;
   END;
```

From the function that I made. for example I got `MAR (march) as V_MONTH`, then I want to concat string `'YTD_AMOUNT_' + MAR`(that I got from function) inside my select query like this below :

```
SELECT SUM(NVL (SALDO_AWAL_TAHUN, 0) + (NVL ('YTD_AMOUNT_'
  || GET_MONTH_NAME (3), 0))) AS value
FROM Table_A
```

I want the result will be :

```
500 (SALDO_AWAL_TAHUN + YTD_AMOUNT_MAR  )
```

But it shown me "Invalid number"
I'm searching so much about my case in google but i'm still not find it yet

Comment: Can you explain by an example and a sample output?

Comment: Please add code of function, table structure, some sample data and output you are expecting.

Comment: I made update already on my questions. Please let me know if you need more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unpivot the columns containing data per month

```
select t.*, substr(t.mon, 12, 3) as m
from table_a unpivot(val for mon in("YTD_AMOUNT_JAN",
                                    "YTD_AMOUNT_FEB",
                                    "YTD_AMOUNT_MAR")) t
/* result:

SALDO_AWAL_TAHUN  BRANCH_ID MON             VAL M
100               001a      YTD_AMOUNT_JAN  200 JAN
100               001a      YTD_AMOUNT_FEB  300 FEB
100               001a      YTD_AMOUNT_MAR  400 MAR

*/
```

Now you can easily select the required data:

```
select res
  from (select substr(t.mon, 12, 3) as m,
               t.saldo_awal_tahun + val as res
          from (select *
                  from table_a unpivot(val for mon in("YTD_AMOUNT_JAN",
                                                      "YTD_AMOUNT_FEB",
                                                      "YTD_AMOUNT_MAR"))) t)
 where m = GET_MONTH_NAME(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the function name and pass the variable like this:

SELECT NVL (SALDO_AWAL_TAHUN, 0) + NVL ('YTD_AMOUNT_' || GET_MONTH_NAME(3), 0) AS value from Table_A;